# Writing data to DynamoDB getting slower and slower over time

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm migrating some data from mysql to dynamoDB using PHP. Its about 15000000 rows, and 7GB.

But, for some unknown reason, the consumed write capacity drops a lot after a while running the script.

It I try again some hours later, it will get full speed again.

The partition key is all unique! There is no sort key.

Any reason for this? I'm new to dynamoDB, and I cant imagine why this would happen.

[image]

Comment: How are you ensuring, the machine from where u are running the migration is not limiting on the needed machine resources?

Comment: The network out is low on the machines where the script is running. I'm using 4 of them... But I don't know if it is because the network is low, or because dynamoDB is slow.

Comment: Are they constrained on other resources such as cpu, memory etc?

Comment: I am expecting the bottle neck on the resources performing the migration, rather than dynamo db.